# Differential equation inequality help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $x$ be the solution to the following differential equation :
>   $$x'(t)=\sin(t^2x)\>,\>x(0)=0.1$$
>   Show that
>
> $(a)\quad \left|x(t)\right|\le0.1+t\quad\forall t>0$
>
> $(b)\quad \left|x(t)\right|\le0.1e^\frac{t^3}{3}\quad\forall t>0$

$(a)$ **I need help in verifying my solution.** Using the formula :
$$\text{For the IVP}:x'(t)=f(t,x)\>,\>x(t_0)=x_0\\x(t)=x_0+\int_{t_0}^{t}f(s,x(s))\,ds$$
We have
\begin{align}
\left|x(t)\right|&=\left|0.1+\int_{0}^{t}\sin(s^2x(s))\,ds\right|\\\\
&\le 0.1+\int_{0}^{t}\left|\sin(s^2x(s))\right|\,ds\\\\
&\le 0.1+\int_{0}^{t}1\,ds\\\\
&=0.1+t\quad\forall t>0
\end{align}
**Another doubt is that in the solution provided, there is this step :**
$$\text{Note that }\left|\sin(t^2x_1)-\sin(t^2x_2)\right|\le t^2\left|x_1-x_2\right|\quad\forall t,x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}$$
**How is it relevant in showing the inequality?**

$(b)$
\begin{align}
\left|x(t)\right|&=\left|0.1+\int_{0}^{t}\sin(s^2x(s))\,ds\right|\\\\
&\le 0.1+\int_{0}^{t}\left|\sin(s^2x(s))\right|\,ds\\\\
&\le 0.1+\int_{0}^{t}\left|s^2x(s)\right|\,ds\\\\
\end{align}
Using Gronwall's inequality, we have
\begin{align}
\left|x(t)\right|&\le0.1+\int_{0}^{t}\left|s^2x(s)\right|\,ds\\\\
&\le 0.1+\int_{0}^{t}0.1s^2e^{\left|\int_{s}^{t}z^2\,dz\right|}\,ds\\\\
&\le 0.1+\int_{0}^{t}0.1s^2e^{\int_{s}^{t}z^2dz}\,ds\\\\
&\le 0.1e^{\int_{0}^{t}z^2\,dz}\\\\
&= 0.1e^\frac{t^3}{3}\quad\forall t>0
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Gronwall inequality, since $\left|x(t)\right|\le0.1+\int_{0}^{t}\left|s^2x(s)\right|\,ds$, we have

$$
|x(t)|\le 0.1\exp\left(\int_0^ts^2\right)=0.1\exp\left(\frac{t^3}{3}\right)
$$